# Paypal API showing different behaviour on different machines

Tags: php, laravel, paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

we try to integrate paypal api to our php application. My team member shared the project with me. However, something super strange is happening on my working env. When I click on pay button, I'm getting an invalid request error from the paypal api. however the same project is working all fine on my teammates environment although everything is the same and he is seeing a paypal pop up view for the payment.

```
        $header = array();
        $header[] = 'Content-type: application/json';
        $header[] = 'Authorization: Bearer ' . $this->token . '';
        $url = $this->apiUrl . '/v1/billing/plans';

        $data = '
   {
      "product_id": "' . $this->productId . '",
      "name": "' . $name . '",
      "description": "' . $description . '",
      "billing_cycles": ' . $billingCycles . ',
      "payment_preferences": {
        "auto_bill_outstanding": true,
        "setup_fee": {
          "value": "' . $amount. '",
          "currency_code": "EUR"
        },
        "setup_fee_failure_action": "CONTINUE",
        "payment_failure_threshold": 2
      }
   }
';


        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        $err = curl_errno($ch);
        $errmsg = curl_error($ch);

        curl_close($ch);
        if ($err) {
            return false;
        }
        if ($errmsg) {
            return false;
        } else {
            $json = json_decode($result);

            dd($result);
            return $json->id;
        }
    } else {
        return false;
    }
```

and the error i get is:

```
"{"name":"INVALID_REQUEST","message":"Request is not well-formed, syntactically incorrect, or violates schema.","debug_id":"f2299f25a802c","details":[{"field":"/billing_cycles/0/pricing_scheme/fixed_price/value","value":"40.97999999999999687361196265555918216705322265625","location":"body","issue":"INVALID_PARAMETER_VALUE","description":"The value of a field is invalid."}],"links":[{"href":"https://developer.paypal.com/docs/api/v1/billing/subscriptions#INVALID_REQUEST","rel":"information_link","method":"GET"}]}
```

Note: I doubt that there is a problem with amount as can be seen in the error message however even if i manually change amount to lets say 4, i still see the same double value with so many digits, i tried round($amount) etc but nothing works. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the value have to be a string? It seems like an odd requirement

Comment: sorry i didn't get you, do you mean it is an odd requirement from paypal api side or how we store the amount in json as string?

Comment: After looking into it further it does seem to be a requirement of the paypal payment api. At any rate this seems to be a [floating point precision](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.float.php) issue (see red warning). This could yield different results based on PHP version or whether or not PHP is  running on 32bit or 64bit (and is itself compiled appropriately). At any rate since you are dealing with currency you should do `round($value, 2)` to ensure you always only get 2 decimal places for the value (or however many the currency considers important)

Comment: thanks for the swift answer. i tried it now with rounding 2 digits as you showed but im still getting the same error with the huge digits :/

Comment: To confirm the issue seems to mention the value at `$billingCycles[0]['pricing_scheme']['fixed_price']['value']` and you'd need to round the value before putting the variable in the request body variable

Comment: do you mean i should round the value outside of the $data variable. I just did that, doesn't also seem to work :( what a headache

Comment: Hi @apokryfos upon looking a closer look at the error, and combining what you said i was able to fix the problem. not in the piece of code i shared but a little above in my source code, i had the error where paypal api requires a string value but we pass only integer value. fixing that solved my problem. pls share your comment as an answer so that i can approve that.